# asp:hyperLink NavigateURL and Eval functions

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink, eval

What is the correct syntax to add a Eval() function to the NavigateURL attribute of asp:HyperLink?

I am trying to achieve the below:

```
NavigateUrl="http://home/?<%# Eval("U_ID") %>"
```

The link should be "http://home? + the value of U_ID"
But the syntax isn't right I know. Whats the correct spelling?

Comment: Show an example of the rendered URL you are looking for? Or is this an SEO friendly URL achieved with routing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with this

```
 NavigateUrl='http://home/?<%# Eval("U_ID") %>'
```

or

```
 NavigateUrl='<%# "http://home/?" + (string)Eval("U_ID") %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't works my site. I found the following solution:

```
NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("~/Home.aspx?{0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("U_ID").ToString())) %>'
```