# How to handle single quote in query string parameter values inside Eval for navigateurl property of hyperlink

Tags: asp.net

Inside `Gridview` control
If my `ID_Logon` value has single quote characters in it, then the string gets terminated at the single quote.
for eg, if `Id_Logon = O'connel`
then only the O is being passed as a parameter. How to pass the whole string?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LogonID" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="hyperlink1"
             NavigateUrl='<%#"EditLogon.aspx?ID=" + Eval("ID_Logon")%>'
               Text='<%# Bind("ID_Logon")%>' runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NavigateUrl='http://home/?<%# Eval("U_ID") %>'
```

or

```
NavigateUrl='<%# "http://home/?" + (string)Eval("U_ID") %>'
```

source [asp:hyperLink NavigateURL and Eval functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981280/asphyperlink-navigateurl-and-eval-functions)

Comment: What if U_ID value has a single quote in it?

Comment: Doesn't matter it will be the part of query string