# asp:hyperLink NavigateURL and double quote characters error

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

What is the correct syntax to the NavigateURL attribute of asp:HyperLink?

Error came when I used double quote characters.
(Eg:-Number of "visits accessing our community" health physiotherapy services )

```
 <RAD:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="KPI" DataField="DisplayName" UniqueName="KPIName" GroupByExpression="DisplayName Group By DisplayName">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("DisplayName") %>' ID="lblKPI" runat="server" Visible="false" />
                        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkKpi" rel='<%# Eval("DisplayName") %>' Text='<%# Eval("DisplayName") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("KPIID","~/Authorised/PerformanceManagement/PerformanceManagement.aspx?Kpi={0}") %>' Target="_blank"></asp:HyperLink>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </RAD:GridTemplateColumn>
```

**Result**

[image]

How to handle the error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `HtmlEncode` for the values

```
Text='<%# HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Eval("DisplayName")) %>'
```

Or

```
NavigateUrl='<%# "~/Authorised/PerformanceManagement/PerformanceManagement.aspx?Kpi=" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Eval("DisplayName")) %>'
```

Comment: It wasn't works. I think error in NavigateURL attribute.

Comment: See my update. But you need to escape those characters for use in an URL

Comment: **Parser Error**
  Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

 Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.

Comment: I used rel attribute. It was error. I used first solution.  `rel='<%# HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Eval("DisplayName")) %>'` Now it is working fine.Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating a URL in the code behind file.

See [Dynamically set a hyperlink control's NavigateUrl property inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594143/dynamically-set-a-hyperlink-controls-navigateurl-property-inline).

Comment: Will you please refer this url: http://samgaut.blogspot.com/2012/08/dynamically-build-asphyperlink.html

Comment: If this does not help the please try  <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/MyWebsite/info.aspx?n={0}", DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.num").ToString())%>' >Text</asp:HyperLink>

Comment: Please refer this url : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981280/asphyperlink-navigateurl-and-eval-functions?rq=1

Comment: I used rel attribute. It was error. I used first solution. `rel='<%# HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Eval("DisplayName")) %>` Now it is working fine.Thank you